# How to access ExtendedData/SimpleData from KMLfile using openlayers 2.x?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, fields-attributes

Is is possible to access  SimpleData tag using Openlayers 2.x library? I have a KML file exported from QGis and it stores description data SimpleData tag "<>". i know that there is a way getting the name and the description tag like this :feature.attributes.name , feature.attributes.description. the kml attribute data are like this:SimpleData> name="NAME_0">Syria /SimpleData> so i suppose that i should call it by the name of the attribute.

Any help ?